# Regular expression for matching numbers without commas

Tags: regex

I am stuck trying to get numbers without commas in front of a number.

Here is what I am using:

```
^(\d{1,3})$|(,\d{3})$
```

Here is the match:

```
3
62
115
112,266,455
989,564,654
137,150
,137,150
```

I don't want `,137,150`.

Comment: It is possible that by tagging this with a language/system (as suggested in the tag tooltip) non-re answers/more suitable answers could be given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming those matches you listed should all be the same match, you should combine those groups and allow `,###` to be repeated any number of times:

```
^\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*$
```

Comment: And then, one day, a user will use India-style decimal marks. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark e.g. `1,00,000,00,00,000` :-)

Comment: @Denis: Does anybody actually do it like that? Three places, two places, two places, three places, two places…? I’m scared :'(

Comment: Yeah, some people actually do. A bit over a billion of them, lol. :-D

Comment: @user2329342: If this is the answer, could you accept it by checking the checkmark? Thanks!